# VBA - convert a very small value to percentage

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I am trying to convert a really small value to percentage but I got a strange number. For example of the small value, -8.45129E-05.

Currently, I am using below code for conversion.

```
Cells(i, 6) = FormatPercent(Cells(i, 6), 8, , vbTrue)
```

I got a result of -845.13% if the small value is -8.45129E-05, but the correct result should be -0.00845129%. I guess the issue is caused by the E-05. Any suggestions to fix that?

**Example with new excel file.**

Line 10 column 6 should be -0.0084513% (122.21/122.76-1)-(1291/1296.7-1) (Column D to F is calculated by Sub and Column H to J is calculated by hand)

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel/VBA do you use?

Comment: Excel 2011 mac version

Comment: Please add other statements of your code. It seems your problem is related to them.

Comment: Added. Thanks a lot

Comment: You passed `8` as `NumDigitsAfterDecimal` argument of `FormatPercent`, while it is `2` in your previous line. And would you add the data of the line that you have problem with?

Comment: It should be 8, Typo. Attached a screen shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153771/discussion-between-mehdi-javan-and-pak-ho-cheung).

Comment: Please see my update. I guess it is excel problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by change

```
Cells(i, 6) = FormatPercent(Cells(i, 6), 8, , vbTrue)
```

to

```
Cells(i, 6) = FormatPercent(Cells(i, 6) * 10000, 8, , vbTrue)
Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 6) / 10000
```

I know this is not the most correct answer. If you have a better one, I will vote yours.